# How to use default php classes in my namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I am using namespaces to resolve class name conflicts in two of the SDKs I am using in my project

I have declared a name space in one of the file like

```
namespace temp;

class abc extends stdClass
{
  // my class def
}
```

when i am hitting this code i get error says temp/stdClass not found, so I need to use all default php structures, interfaces like iterators etc. so how can I import the default namespace of php or do any another setting I am missing?

Comment: you have declare that stdclass belong from global scope using ,     use \stdClass

Comment: `class abc extends \stdClass` would also work.

Comment: but my problem is I have already built SDKs and if I do so I will have to modify 100's of lines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `\` before any global class, function and constant (`stdClass` in your example). [Here](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) is more information how to use namespaces.

Comment: but my problem is I have already built SDKs and if I do so I will have to modify 100's of lines. is there any thing like use default so all default classes and interfaces can be extended or implemented

Comment: in that case declare namespace after class declaration (after class completes )

Comment: @RupeshPatel Almost any IDE has _replace all_ tool.

Comment: @Poonam Can you Pls share your suggestion with a bit of code so I can accept the answer

Comment: upvote from me .. it took me a bit of searching to figure out what was going on here .. thanks for this answer.  @miniHouse, the example would be to simply change the line in the sample question to be like this `class abc extends \stdClass`