# Cannot load class with require_once when using namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, slim-3

I'm using `Slim` for develop a simple `REST API`, and I'm facing a weird problem. Essentially I configured the `API` to load all the classes using the autoloader via composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Controllers\\": "app/controllers",
        "App\\Helpers\\": "app/helpers",
        "App\\Models\\": "app/models",
        "App\\Services\\": "app/services",
        "Core\\": "src/core",
        "Core\\Helpers\\": "src/helpers",
        "Core\\Libraries\\": "src/libraries"
    }
}
```

I have created a class called `GoogleSync` which must include the `Google API php library`, so I've included in the following way:

```
<?php namespace Core\Libraries;

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once __DIR__ . '/external/google-api-php-client/Google_Client.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/external/google-api-php-client/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';


class GoogleSync
{
    /**
     * Google API Client
     *
     * @var Google_Client
     */
    protected $client;

    public function __construct($api_settings)
    {
        var_dump(file_exists(__DIR__ . "/external/google-api-php-client/Google_Client.php"));
        $this->client = new Google_Client();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Core\Libraries\Google_Client' not found in
>   A:\Programmi\MAMP\htdocs\ci3-api\src\libraries\GoogleSync.php:44

for a strange reason if I include in the class `Google_Client` the following namespace:

```
Core\Libraries
```

the code is able to load the class. So I suspect that the `require_once` is not able to inject the class 'cause there is an autoloader logic, but I could be wrong.

Also, the method `file_exist` in the constructor return `true`.

What's happening?

Comment: You're calling it within a namespace so it attempts to use that namespace, maybe try instantiating it like this: $this->client = new \Google_Client(); to ignore the namespace.

Comment: Thanks the problem was really easy to fix, if you answer the question I will accept, have a good day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use default php classes in my namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247820/how-to-use-default-php-classes-in-my-namespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling it within a namespace so it attempts to use that namespace, maybe try instantiating it like this: `$this->client = new \Google_Client();` to ignore the namespace.

[Possible duplicate of this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247820/how-to-use-default-php-classes-in-my-namespace)